# I am trying to store the data read by fs in a variable. But I am getting undefined as output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, filesystems, fs

[I am trying to store the data read by fs in a variable. But I am getting undefined as output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL4L0.png)

```
const fs = require("fs");

var a;
fs.readFile("analogData.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  a = data;
});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require("fs");

let a;

fs.readFile("analogData.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {

a = data;
console.log(a);

});
```

You might have not created the text file.
SO, create it and run the program again.

Comment: I have created a text file.

Comment: const fs = require("fs");

let a;

fs.readFile("analogData.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {

a = data;
console.log(a);

});
console.log(a)

The last console.log is showing undefined

Comment: put console.log(a) inside.

Comment: If a put console.log(a) inside in the scope then I will get the correct value but I need the value outside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

For console.log outside of the callback function, it always gives undefined. Since it executes before "a" variable being set in the callback. Callback function runs after console.log.